# How to remove only one user's reaction from an emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

#### My Code:

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.id === "<message ID>")
    reaction.message.reactions.cache.forEach((reaction) =>
      reaction.remove(user.id)
    );
});
```

---

#### My Problem:

The code above mostly works. Whenever someone reacts to the specified message, it will remove their reaction. However, it removes everyone *else's* reaction (to that emoji) along with it. How can I only remove one specific user's reaction from an emoji?

Comment: look at [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and filter those that don't match your criteria

Comment: What part should I filter?

Comment: please share some data from `reaction`

Comment: The `reaction` argument is the `MessageReaction` object. Here are the [`Client#messageReactionAdd` event docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) and the [`MessageReaction` class docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works:

```js
reaction.message.reactions.cache.first() // fetch the reaction (you could use `.get()` as well)
  .users.remove(user.id); // remove the user
```

---

I'm really stumped as to why *this* works but my original function does not.

---

Edit: I'm an idiot. I was supposed to use the `users` property. `reaction.users.remove()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Discord.js docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-reactions-by-user):

```
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
try {
    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
        await reaction.users.remove(userId);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work, the `for` loop isn't even triggered, although it doesn't trigger the `catch` statement either.